# Cannot connect to MySQL database after implementing NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, redundancy, mysql-cluster, ndb

I'm trying to shift from a single instance of a mysql database to using a cluster for redundancy purposes, following the steps I found from [here](https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-20-04/), I thought this was the solution I needed, but I'm getting an error now that I can't seem to find a solution for online. I've created the cluster config.ini file, and modified mysql's my.cnf file to point to my management server, but when I try to connect to MySQL now, I get an error `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104`, and I can't figure out exactly what is wrong. The NDB manager says all is okay, and the MySQL exits successfully with error code 0 for success, but it is constantly stuck in a status of "server startup in progress" and gives me an error 22 for an "invalid argument". Please help, I've been at this for over a week and cannot for the life of me figure it out.

`systemctl status ndb_mgmd` returns:

```
ndb_mgmd.service - MySQL NDB Cluster Management Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ndb_mgmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-04-11 19:43:56 UTC; 2s ago
    Process: 5463 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 5464 (ndb_mgmd)
      Tasks: 12 (limit: 8500)
     Memory: 2.4M
        CPU: 52ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ndb_mgmd.service
             └─5464 /usr/sbin/ndb_mgmd -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
```

`systemctl status mysql` returns:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2023-04-11 19:44:09 UTC; 825ms ago
    Process: 5733 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 5741 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 22 (Invalid argument)
      Tasks: 31 (limit: 8500)
     Memory: 364.0M
        CPU: 524ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─5741 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Trying to connect with `mysql -u root -p` and then entering the password gives:

`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104`

/etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
# Options for mysqld process:
ndbcluster                      # run NDB storage engine

[mysql_cluster]
# Options for NDB Cluster processes:
ndb-connectstring=192.168.195.101  # location of management server
```

/var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini:

```
[ndbd default]
# Options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:
NoOfReplicas=1  # Number of replicas

[ndb_mgmd]
# Management process options:
hostname=192.168.195.101 # Hostname of the manager
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for the log files

[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.195.167 # Hostname/IP of the second data node
NodeId=2                       # Node ID for this data node
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[mysqld]
# SQL node options:
hostname=192.168.195.101 # In our case the MySQL server/client is on the same Droplet as the cluster manager
```

I've tripled check the IP addresses, but ever since I started trying to use the second unit to cluster, I haven't even been able to connect to MySQL to do any further tests. How to fix this?

Comment: What is the latest message in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` ?  It should give you a few error lines before the "aborting" report ..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Zak! The last message in mysql's error.log file is: `unkown option '--ndbcluster' - Aborting`

Comment: Maybe take a look at [This article](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/all-products/9781847199942/1/ch01lvl1sec13/installing-and-starting-sql-nodes) to make sure your cluster is properly set up and connecting ..  IT contains an area speaking to that exact error.

Comment: Before 8.0.31 one need to use mysqld from a mysql-cluster package to have the support for --ndbcluster. 
Since 8.0.31 the standard mysqld should also support --ndbcluster.
Unless your package manager decided to explicitly exclude support for ndbcluster, in that case you still need to use mysqld from mysql-cluster packages.